# Android Default Preference xml file format

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences, android-xml

I appear to be the only person on the internet who can't figure this out, but when I use

```
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preference, false);
```

what is the syntax of the XML file for the default settings. I simply want to set two preferences to true.

I have tried the normal android string resource format, but nothing seems to work. Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not the only person who doesn't know this. Even am struggling to know the file format of the XML. Finally i found the answer! There you go!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <EditTextPreference android:key="CLIENT_HOMESCREEN_TITLE"
                android:defaultValue="Home Screen"/>
    <EditTextPreference android:key="CLIENT_ADMIN_BUTTON"
                android:defaultValue="Admin"/>
    <EditTextPreference android:key="CLIENT_PLAYER_BUTTON"
                android:defaultValue="Player"/>
    <EditTextPreference android:key="CLIENT_SAVE_BUTTON"
                android:defaultValue="Save"/>
    <EditTextPreference android:key="CLIENT_CANCEL_BUTTON"
                android:defaultValue="Cancel"/>
    <EditTextPreference android:key="CLIENT_SERVER_SETUP_IP"
                android:defaultValue="IP:"/>
    <EditTextPreference android:key="CLIENT_SERVER_SETUP_PORT"
                android:defaultValue="Port:"/>
    <EditTextPreference android:key="CLIENT_SERVER_SETUP_TITLE"
                android:defaultValue="Server Setup"/>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: I forgot what I ended up doing, and I haven't had to deal with it for a while now, but if this is the xml, thanks, it will certainly help me in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Use [android:defaultValue](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#attr_android%3adefaultValue) like so:

```
<CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="my_pref"
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:title="@string/pref_title_my_pref"
        android:summary="@string/pref_summary_my_pref"/>
```

Comment: The problem with this is that if I don't go to the settings page first, my preferences won't be set to default. The android documentation says that if you need to set default preferences, use

    PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues

in the onCreate of your main Activity. The problem is I don't know how the xml file for that function should be structured....

Comment: If your preferences are stored in e.g. `res/xml/settings.xml` then all you have to do is call [setDefaultValues](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html#setDefaultValues%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20boolean%29) with `R.xml.settings` from the main activity's onCreate method.

Comment: You might also want to specify true for the _readAgain_ parameter because otherwise the default values are only set once and you do not get the default values for newly introduced preferences keys. The implementation remembers that it has already set the defaults in a private settings key.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I have read all the documentation, but the issue I am having is i don't know how to make the xml file to provide. I know how to create the file, but the actual xml that goes in there escapes me. I tried the standard android values format (tage of resources and string, etc) but android doesn't like it. All I need is a sample of what could go into R.xml.settings and I will be super happy. Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: Here is an example: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/res/xml/preferences.html

Comment: Even better: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html

Answer (score 0):

**what is the syntax of the XML file for the default settings. I simply want to set two preferences to true.**

For this just set default value to `true`

Whatever **default values you have provided in preference xml file**, that will be set.

Comment: I could check at the beginning of my main activity if these settings are assigned, and if not, set them to the default values, but android provides PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues to make this more maintainable and less of a massive pain for larger number of settings. When I open skype for the first time on android, it has all the settings preset, and I have to assume that this is done with PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues, not 200 lines of checking if the prefs were set before.

Comment: That's why this method is available :)